# Firefox doesn't render my icon fonts (@font-face)

Tags: css, font-face

I started using icon fonts.
I got this bit working with IE8+, Chrome and Safari. However it is not working with Firefox.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'tr-icon';
      src:url('/fonts/myFont.eot?16p15w');
      src:url('/fonts/myFont.eot?#iefix16p15w') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('/fonts/myFont.woff?16p15w') format('woff'),
            url('/fonts/myFont.ttf?16p15w') format('truetype'),
            url('/fonts/myFont.svg?16p15w#myFont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.tr-icon-blah:before {
    font-family: 'tr-icon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    content: "\e605";
}
```

It is shown as being a character code in a box. I tried to access all my src with firefox and it worked.
Not sure what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You may try removing the lines with .eot file type from the font-face declarations, if I remember correctly, FireFox had issues with it in the past.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still having : 
content: "";

Comment: hmm, it seems like this is a common issue with the Gecko engine. You might try some of the suggestions in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17993554/806599